# Open link within the Ionic app

Tags: android, listview, hyperlink, ionic-framework

I have a link which comes from

```
<div class="list">
  <a ng-repeat="entry in entries" class="item" ng-click="browse(entry.link)">
               <b>{{entry.title}}</b><br>
               <span ng-bind-html="entry.contentSnippet"></span>
  </a>

</div>
```

But, as of now it has to be opened in a browser instead of the app in which the link is listed. Just wondering if there is some way to make the link open within the app itself. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
<div class="list">
  <a ng-repeat="entry in entries" class="item"
onclick="window.open('{{entry.link}}', '_system', 'location=yes'); return false;"
>
          <b>{{entry.title}}</b><br>
            <span ng-bind-html="entry.contentSnippet"></span>
  </a>

</div>
```

Comment: a small doubt. Doesn't _system denote using system browser than inappbrowser ?

Comment: I used '_blank' and 'location=yes'